# Parcel build & IE11: regenerator-transform fails because it finds a for-of statement (ForOfStatement) within a generator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, parcel, webex

I try to build a small app based upon Webex web SDK, internally requiring regenerator-transform.

Here is my `package.json` simple file:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "yarn build",
    "build": "parcel index.html --out-dir dist --public-url ./",
    "deploy": "git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages",
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "urijs": "^1.19.2",
    "webex": "^1.80.147"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 2 major versions and >1%"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

Here is my `.babelrc` file too:

```
{
    presets : [ 'es2015', 'es2016' ]
}
```

It works perfectly when I use `browserslist` preset `latest Chrome`, but with this current query, I have this error:

`[...]pkijs/src/SignedCertificateTimestampList.js: unknown Statement of type "ForOfStatement"`

Full stack trace:

```
  /Users/guillaumepotier/Sites/webex-sdk/node_modules/pkijs/src/SignedCertificateTimestampList.js: /Users/guillaumepotier/Sites/webex-sdk/node_modules/pkijs/src/SignedCertificateTimestampList.js: unknown Statement of type "ForOfStatement"
    at Emitter.Ep.explodeStatement (/Users/guillaumepotier/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/regenerator-transform/lib/emit.js:587:13)
    at /Users/guillaumepotier/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/regenerator-transform/lib/emit.js:323:12
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Emitter.Ep.explodeStatement (/Users/guillaumepotier/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/regenerator-transform/lib/emit.js:322:22)
    at Emitter.Ep.explode (/Users/guillaumepotier/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/regenerator-transform/lib/emit.js:280:40)
    at PluginPass.<anonymous> (/Users/guillaumepotier/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/regenerator-transform/lib/visit.js:111:17)
    at PluginPass.<anonymous> (/Users/guillaumepotier/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/regenerator-transform/lib/util.js:28:17)
    at newFn (/Users/guillaumepotier/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:179:21)
    at NodePath._call (/Users/guillaumepotier/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:55:20)
    at NodePath.call (/Users/guillaumepotier/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:42:17)
```

It seems the problem is raised by `regenerator-transform` and the "ForOfStatement" within a generator, I tried many babel different configs but in vain.

My `parcel --version` gives me `1.12.4`

Do you have any clue for that, how do you ship code with Parcel for IE11?